Spoken language of the Hobbits in LotR
Yesterday, while milling over iconic lines from the Lord of the Rings trilogy, something started bugging me – Whenever the Hobbits are amongst themselves wouldn't they speak… well 'Hobbitish' or at least some kind of dialect, different from plain common?
Disclaimer: As I am not that well-versed in the deep lore of the Tolkien universe and haven't watched the movies, let alone read the books in years, so please excuse any kinds of mistakes I make while trying to formulate my question(s).
After a bit of research, I had gleamed, that the Hobbits supposedly mostly spoke "Westron", the shared common language of Middle-Earth at the time the main story takes place. A few sources mentioned the dialect "Hobbitish", specifically attributed to the Shire.
From that point onward my curiosity led me to the next question – would it be possible to translate any of the iconic lines, to reconstruct how they would have sounded, without being translated for us, the observers?
The available "translators" or dictionaries were few and far between.
Many hours of research later, I knew I had hit a brick wall, when I stumbled over multiple articles, forum entries, etc. that all but confirmed, that even the Elvish languages – which easily seemed to be the most popular and well documented – are not even close to being "speakable".
So with this preamble let me break everything down to my two main questions:

What was/were the spoken language(s) of the Hobbits (during the era where the plot of LotR takes place)? Am I correct with my assumptions stated above?

Are there any resources for these languages (e.g. extensive dictionaries), that I maybe just didn't find or is it more or less impossible to translate more than a few words, since they just aren't documented well enough?


And as a bonus question, tacked on at the end: is it documented whether these languages have a different script, just like e.g., Tolkien's Elvish does?
That would be all, I hope some LotR nerds can help me out here and at least get the first part of my question sorted.

This seems a bit unfocused. Maybe try editing out the 'chatter' and concentrating on a single answerable question

please do not ask multiple questions in one post ... there is no way to select multiple correct answers

It seems that the 'translation' of Westron into English in Tolkien's works was so thorough that you're not being able to get farther than a few names, see detailed discussion here.

1) What was/were the spoken language(s) of the Hobbits (during the era where the plot of LotR takes place)? Am I correct with my assumptions stated above?
It is well-documented that the Hobbits speak the common tongue of the Men of the West, Tolkien noted that the Hobbit dialect has shifted enough Pippin sounded a bit odd in Gondor:

The Westron tongue made in the pronouns of the second person (and
often also in those of the third) a distinction, independent of
number, between 'familiar and 'deferential' forms . It was, however,
one of the peculiarities of of Shire-usage that the deferential forms
had gone out of colloquial use.



Peregrin Took, for instance, in his first few days in Minas Tirith
used the familiar for people of all ranks, including the Lord Denethor
himself. This may have amused the aged Steward, but it must have
astonished his servants. No doubt this free use of the familiar forms helped to spread the popular rumour that Peregrin was a person of very high rank in his own country.

This is, of course, analogous to the you/thou distinction which once existed in English, though in modern usage, everyone uses the deferential word ('you') rather than the familiar one, which would make us sound terribly formal a few centuries ago.

To answer question (1), which is clear enough, in the appendices to LotR, writing on the history of the Hobbits, JRRT says (my emphasis):

It was in these early days, doubtless, that the Hobbits learned their letters and began to write after the manner of the Dúnedain, who had in their turn long before learned the art from the Elves. And in those days also they forgot whatever languages they had used before, and spoke ever after the Common Speech, the Westron as it was named, that was current through all the lands of the kings from Arnor to Gondor, and about all the coasts of the Sea from Belfalas to Lune. Yet they kept a few words of their own, as well as their own names of months and days, and a great store of personal names out of the past.


Answering a question that you've openly acknowledged is off-topic isn't a great idea.
